# In visual studio how can I prevent switching to the last grouped docked tab window when typing the end key

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In visual studio on the right hand side I have the following windows grouped together: Codeium, Solution Explorer, Git, Properties, and Live Share. I frequently have at least both Codeium and the Solution Explorer pinned.  When Codeium is to the left of the solution explorer and I am typing a prompt, the currently selected tab will switch to the right most pinned tab, in this example, the solution explorer.  If I try to mitigate this by making Codeium the right most pinned tab, than the keyboard event is just swallowed.  This is very annoying as I frequently find myself needing to navigate my cursor to the end of the line in my Codeium prompts.  The only way I have found to deal with this so far is to unpin all the other windows, which is an annoying extra step to have to do and then possibly undo.